# Is the difference of a convex function and a strictly convex function convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Given two functions, $f$ which is convex and $g$ which is strictly convex, is the difference $f-g$ convex?

My impulse is to say no, since $-g$ should be concave, but I'm trying to show this explicitly.

I've been trying to use the definition of convexity/strict convexity to get somewhere on this:
$$f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda )y) \le \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda )f(y)$$
$$g(\lambda x+(1-\lambda )y) < \lambda g(x) + (1-\lambda )g(y)$$

But to see anything useful I'd need to subtract the second equation from the first one. Can I do that? We'd then end up with a weird combination of less than and greater than statements, which feels wrong.

Any suggestions here? Is there a better way to get a result?
Thank you!

Comment: Take $f=0$ and g be any strictly convex non concave function.

Answer (score 1):

Just pick a counter example, let $f=0$ and $g=x^4$,

then $f-g=-x^4$ and it is not convex.